# Mysql : Use IF in TRUNCATE

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the query, simplified.

```
SELECT `a`, TRUNCATE(`b` / 1000, 3) AS `b`
FROM (
    ...                         
) AS `m`
GROUP BY `a`
ORDER BY `a`
```

What i'm trying to do is change the number of decimal places (actual 3) based on the value of **b**.

So i tried this:

```
SELECT `a`, TRUNCATE(`b` / 1000, IF(`b` < 10, 2, 3)) AS `b` ...
```

and this

```
SELECT `a `, IF(`b ` < 10, TRUNCATE(`b ` / 1000, 2), TRUNCATE(`b ` / 1000, 3)) AS `b `
```

If `b` is less than 10, i want **3** decimal places, otherwise **2**.

But this doesn't seem to work ...

Resources : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: but hum, if `b < 10` then `b / 1000 < 0.01` so keeping only 2 decimal will always return "0.00" ?!

Comment: Sorry, question updated

Comment: If b is 9 -> 9/1000 = 0.009 -> i want 0.009. But if b > 9 , like 3556 , 3556 / 1000 = 3.556 -> i want 3.55 and not 3.556.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the values position that you put in your query

```
 SELECT `a `, IF(b  < 10, TRUNCATE(b  / 1000, 3), TRUNCATE(b  / 1000, 2))
```

AS b

if(a<1,2,3) means if a<1 then 2 will come as a value in your result so you have to switch your values position

use `round`

```
SELECT a , IF(b  < 10, round((b  / 1000), 2), round((b  / 1000), 3) ) AS b
```

The ROUND() function rounds a number to a specified number of decimal places.

example `SELECT ROUND(345.156, 2);` result = 345.16

```
     SELECT ROUND(345.156, 2);  result = 345.156
```

If you don't want round then TRUNCATE  will shown   0.00 in case of b value less than 10, so what do you mean by not working ?

You need 3 decimal place when b<10 so you have to change the position of yours query result

Comment: ROUND() round off the result, i don't want this.

Comment: @Whiteboard if you don't want round fine but trancate also works fine https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75b0955b4692c8defde3ea2f2320709a here link checked im

Comment: @Whiteboard could you please tell me what would be your output in case of b=9

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced the order of queries to run, in case of true/false evaluation in `If()`. Following may work:

```
SELECT `a `, 
        IF(`b ` < 10, 
           TRUNCATE(`b ` / 1000, 3), 
           TRUNCATE(`b ` / 1000, 2)
          ) AS `b `
```